# How to know the directory name for PHP version for path '/usr/lib/php/{number_name}'? (Install xdebug)

Tags: php, configuration, xdebug

Trying to install Xdebug for several PHP versions.

I need to add configuration to xdebug.so for specific php version.

xdebug.so file placed in `/usr/lib/php/{number_name}/xdebug.so`, where `{number_name}` relates to PHP of some version.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow =), please check here how to ask a good question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Spending a few extra minutes writing the question may significantly improve attention the community will give to it.

Comment: @NikitaKarpenko Numbers like `20190902`? It's a PHP API version -- run `php -i` for that version in terminal (or `phpinfo()` in your PHP code) and you will see it in the very first table with general info.

Comment: @LazyOne yes, its works for me. Thx!

Commnad: php7.4 -i | grep 'PHP Extension\|PHP API'. 

By the way, for 5.6 version those of two praemters was a little bit defferent  (by 1 digit)